# Why does adding ".0" in C++ arithmetic functions give out the answer in decimal points?

Tags: c++, function, math

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{   
    //Returns Seven divided by three is 2
    std::cout << "Seven divided by three is " <<  7/3  << std::endl;

    //Return Seven divided by three is 2.33333
    std::cout << "Seven divided by three is " <<  7.0/3  << std::endl; 
    std::cout << "Seven divided by three is " <<  7.0/3.0  << std::endl;
}
```

How does adding `.0` to the end of a number return a decimal answer even though I have not put a float or double variable in the code?

Comment: Because constants have data type

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: `7/3 = integer`    `7/3.0 = double`  doubles have decimal points, integers to not

Comment: " I have not put a float or double" yes you did, what else type should `7` or `7.0` be?

Comment: `7.0` is not an integer.  The presence of the decimal point means it is a floating point number.

Comment: @UKMonkey: IMHO that comment needs sharpening up; all IEEE754 `double` values greater than the 52nd power of 2 are integers.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I am just a beginner in C++. I struggled with this question but now I am clear.

Comment: Indeed, it is not easy to search for the reason until you know the terms. Which is why I've upvoted the question, and don't really understand the downvoting.

Comment: @Bathsheba you're right, "in this case" should've been added, since 7/3 <2^52 :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constants 7 and 3 are integer, while the constants 7.0 and 3.0 are double floating points.

When you divide two integers the result is an integer.

When you divide two floating point numbers or a floating point and an integer, the result is a floating point number with the highest precision of each.

Comment: Your last sentence is not strictly true. If you had a platform with a very very large `int` (128 bit, or even 64 bit) say, then it would still be converted to a `double`, which could come at a precision cost. With the advent of 64 bit `int`, we are nearly there.

Comment: It is not highest precision of each but depends on rules called "integral promotion" - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion

Answer (score 8):

c++ is a strongly typed language. This means every object, even *rvalue* constants, have a type. `7` and `7.0` differ in type. You can see that in a [simple example](https://ideone.com/FLiszY):

```
std::cout << typeid(7).name() << "\n";
std::cout << typeid(7.0).name() << "\n";
```

prints:

```
i
d
```

for `integer` and `double`.

The reason that your division operations cause a double print in the single case of `7.0/3` is because of the rules of [*integral promotion*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). In this case the `3` is promoted to a double and the resulting value is of type double.

Answer (score 1):

Because it makes the operand of type `double` thus causing the entire expression to be of type `double`.

When you append a `.0` character sequence to something that used to be a [integral literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/integer_literal) it  is no longer an integer. It now represents a [floating point literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal) of type `double` which is one of the operands in an expression that is of type `double` so the [operator<<](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) chooses a `double` overload (the fifth one) and outputs the result accordingly.

Expression:

```
7 / 3
```

is of type `int` as both operands are of type `int`.

Expression of:

```
7.0 / 3
```

is of type `double` as at least one of the operands is of type `double`.

Expression:

```
7.0 / 3.0
```

is also of type `double`.